# Notepad++ regex searching

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to search a document with Notepad++ for the following text:

> `A`

eg. a `space` then a capital `A` then a `space`.

I have the following RegExp to do it:

```
\s[A-A]\s?
```

Which almost does it, except it will highlight all the spaces after the `A`, rather than just the first one, which is not what I want.

From what I understand, the `?` after the regex means it should not be doing this?
So maybe it is Notepad that is highlighting this text?

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `[A-A]` is redundant; just use `A` by itself.

Comment: I had to check that `[A-A]` in the [Unicode Converter](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/) to be sure :) Indeed, no need to declare such a character class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a positive look-ahead `(?=\s?)` so that if there is a space after "A" it was not included in the match:

```
\sA(?=\s?)
```

Also, `[A-A]` is in fact just `A`.

Comment: The trailing `\s?` is always redundant, and `(?=\s?)` is always true. Probably some sort of boundary check is needed here.